# How do i send data to outside from nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have a need to send data from my NodeJS server to an outside server. I have tried many codes and searched for this alot, but not getting any proper working example or its not working in my case.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/getFrom', function (req, res) {
var request = require('request');

        // Try 1 - Fail
        /*var options = {
        url: 'http://example.com/synch.php',
        'method': 'POST',
         'body': {"nodeParam":"working"} 

        };
        request(options, callback);
        */

        // Try 2 - Fail
        /*  request({
            // HTTP Archive Request Object 
            har: {
              url: 'http://example.com/synch.php',
              method: 'POST',
              postData: {
                params: [
                  {
                    nodeParam: 'working'
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },callback)*/

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("body " + body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
                res.send(body);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Error " + error);
            res.send(error);
        }
    }
```

/* ------ HTTP ------ */

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'nodeParam' : 'Hello World!'
});

// try 3  - Fail
/*var optionsHTTP = {
  hostname: 'http://example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/synch.php',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

var req1 = http.request(optionsHTTP, function(res1){
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res1.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res1.headers));
  res1.setEncoding('utf8');
  res1.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  res1.on('end', function(){
    console.log('No more data in response.')
  })
});

req1.on('error',function(e){
  console.log('problem with request:' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req1.write(postData);
req1.end();*/
```

/* ------ /HTTP ------ */

Please let me know where I am wrong

Comment: Simplify your question. Choose one of your attempts, list the code and tell us why it failed. What error messages were you getting?

Comment: Have you started a http server? Look into [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working and tested solution :

```
    request({
        url: 'http://example.com/synch.php', //URL to hit
        qs: {nodeParam: 'blog example', xml: xmlData}, //Query string data
        method: 'POST', //Specify the method
    },callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly your request might be failing, but this is a simple and straightforward sample on using the `request` module in npm:

```js
var request = require('request');

var postData = {
 name: 'test123'
}

request({
 url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
 method: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(postData)
}, function(err, response) {
 if (err) {
  return console.error(err);
 };

 console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

This snippet makes a request to a rest API and display the result on the console. The response data is available in the `response.body` property.

Comment: I have updated the example to reflect the changes. I guess this is what you are trying to do. If you get an error from the server it is most probably due to a problem with the jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, not the node.js code itself